# How to gracefully catch jsonwebtoken errors in node & express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, json-web-token

Here is my verification function:

```
exports.validateToken = function(req, res, next){
  var token = req.body.token;
  jwt.verify(token, config.sessionSecret, function(err, decoded) {
     if(err){
         return next(err);
     }else{

        var userToken = jwt.sign(req.body.user, config.secret,{
            expiresIn:10000
        });

        res.json({token: userToken})

    }    
  });
}
```

I'm expecting an error definition but I'm getting an internal server error on top of that:

```
TokenExpiredError: jwt expired
at Object.JWT.verify (/Users/Developer/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/index.js:209:19)
at exports.validateToken (/Users/Developer/app/controllers/user.signing.controller.js:369:9)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/Developer/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:76:5)
at next (/Users/Developer/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:100:13)
at Route.dispatch (/Users/Developer/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:81:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/Developer/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:76:5)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is the error line pointing to `return next(err);` or `var userToken = jwt.sign(req.body.user, config.secret,{`?

Comment: None. To the jwt.verify(...

Comment: So the question is, why isn't `return next(err);` receiving and handling the `err`?

Comment: Yes. I also tried try{..}catch(err){...} to make sure the problem in not return next(err). But same situation.

Comment: I can't see that anything is wrong with the lib: https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/blob/master/index.js#L243 - Is that the module you're using?

Comment: Thanks for looking that up. That's what I felt and there is nothing much there to play with!

Comment: Does it work when the token hasn't expired?

Comment: Tweak your code to try and look at all the arguments: `jwt.verify(token, 'shhhhh', function(err, decoded) { console.log(arguments) ...` - Although it sounds like it never gets that far.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104493/discussion-between-imad-and-adrian-lynch).

Comment: the arguments are ok. The error object populates correctly  
{ [TokenExpiredError: jwt expired]
  name: 'TokenExpiredError',
  message: 'jwt expired',
  expiredAt: Wed Feb 24 2016 20:07:57 GMT-0800 (PST) } I updated the jwt lib to make sure the error is not because of that. but the server still logs those error.

Comment: Oh, then check if it's entering the `if (err)` block. If it is, what happens when it gets passed to `next(err)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

module.exports =  function auth (req,res,next) {
    const token =req.header('x-auth-token')
    if (!token){
        return res.status(401).send('to\'ken not found')
    }
 try{
        const decoded = jwt.decode(token,'m@hf1y')
         req.user = decoded
         next()

 }catch (e) {
     
     return  res.status(400).send('invalid token')
 }
}
```

Warning: This is using `jwt.decode` and not `jwt.verify`. Since JSON Web Token can always be decoded *without knowing the secret key*, the previous code is only valid if it comes from a *trusted* source.

Answer (score 0):

May be user is asking how to handle different types of error or how to inform front end user that your login time is over please re login to continue

```js
if (err) {
  if (err.name == "TokenExpiredError") {
    res.json({ message: "Request Timeout Please Re login"});
  }
} else {
  console.log(err);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

for some reason the next response is not working. So I replaced that with the following code and everything is fine:

```
res.status(401).send({error:'invalid token'});
```

Comment: why not a `401` unauthorized response?

Answer (score -1):

I have tried this in my code. The `res.locals.data` helps to carry data to the calling function.

Just get the data in the calling function as `res.locals.data` and your problem is solved hopefully.

```
if (err) {
    res.locals.data = {
        err: err.name,
        message : err.message
    }
    return next();
}
```